# How to scroll all the way to the bottom of a scrollbar (currently the last two added items are ignored)

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Scrolling functionality currently works, but is not getting to the bottom of the scroll bar; in particular, it stops right before what I need it to scroll into place.

Have tried accessing different elements, refreshing DOM, and different commands.

Here is the applicable js:

```
<script>
        function scroll(){
          $(document).ready(function() {
            var message_blobs = document.getElementsByClassName("message bot");
            var recent_blob = message_blobs[message_blobs.length - 1];
            recent_blob.scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
            })
          }

        // Interacting with the bot when a user submits input.
        function interact() { 
          $(document).ready(function() {
              if($('#user_input').val()!=""){ // If the message was not null.
                // Posting the user input text to the GUI.
                var raw_input = $('#user_input').val();
                $('#chatbox').append('<div class="message user"><div>'+ raw_input +'</div></div>');
                // Resetting the user text.
                $('#user_input').val('');

                // Now to get the bot response. 
                $.get("/get_response", {msg: raw_input}).done(function(data) {
                  $('#chatbox').append('<div class="message bot"><div>'+ data +'</div></div>');
                  })

                // Scrolling the newly added items into view.
                scroll();
                }
            })
          }

        // Calling bot interaction function if enter is hit or the input button is clicked.
        $("#user_input").keypress(function(e) {
          if(e.which == 13) {
            interact();
            }

          });
        $("#enter_button").click(function() {
          interact();
          })
</script>
```

And here is the associated .css:

```
#chatbox{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#inputs{
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto 40px 40px;
  grid-gap: 4px;
}

.button{
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover{
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.message{
  display: flex;
}

.message.user{
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 50%;
}

.message > div{
  margin: 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
}

.message.bot > div{
  margin-left: 50%;
  background-color: teal;
}

.message.user > div{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Here is an image of the actual output:[image: final message blob on right side not visible]

Here is an image of the desired output:
[image: the right bot reply is not scrolled into view]

Comment: Do u tried `recent_blob.scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'});` instead of `recent_blob.scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});` ?

Comment: yea I have tried that